# Grid of images in iOS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I want to create a TabItem in a TabBarController containing a grid of images which a user can select. I know I could use a TableViewController, but that would just show a long list, rather than rows of (for example) 3x4 images.

Is this possible?

Comment: did u search for "grid", "view" and "cocoa-touch"?

Comment: You can use UIScrollView to create a grid of items. You can calculate the total width of the scroll view / num items in each row and add subviews onto the scrollview. If you want to display hundreds of subviews in a grid, you might have to implement your own dequeueing mechanism.

Comment: This question also proved useful in finding a solution to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622209/lazy-loading-of-subviews-into-a-non-paging-uiscrollview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually went with an excellent control from [CocoaControls](http://cocoacontrols.com/) called [DTGridView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dtgridview), but it was a close second to [GMGridView](http://cocoacontrols.com/controls/gmgridview), which was a close second. I found GMGridView a tad too powerful.

One of the things I found relatively easy to do with DTGridView was to override `-(void)drawRect` to add a stacked stack effect using CoreGraphics.

Comment: Thanks for the link to GMGridView.  It's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

Apple has sample code [TiledScrollView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m-DontLinkElementID_26) that demonstrates how to do what you want to do. The guts of the tile reuse is in `layoutSubviews`. Obviously you will need to tweak it to your own tasks... but it's always nice to have some working code to start with ;-) Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is what you may have been referring to in your answer?  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m-DontLinkElementID_26

Comment: This does look like an excellent starting point for anyone wanting to create a custom control, but in my case I went with one of the many GridView controls available.