# Tutorial for Image Rows and columns?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2, uiimagepickercontroller

how would I go about making a view where there are say 4 rows and 4 columns of pictures and when you click on on it expands to the full screen? I can't store the images in the photos library and display them that way, I need to store and display all the images using only images I could import into the project. Could someone point me to a good tutorial or give me an example? It would be something like this: http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/071/Purple/2d/7d/4d/mzl.lawxddbu.320x480-75.jpg   Sorry for the dumb question but I don't know what this is called so I cant search for a tutorial on it.

Thanks!

-Shredder2794

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003220/grid-of-images-in-ios) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866766/how-to-create-a-gallery-on-ios) answer your question? You don't mention how much help you need or how comfortable you're with iOS Development.

If you need a full blown free course on iOS Programming, check [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225) - it's from Stanford university, covers the new iOS 5 and you can watch for free on your iPhone/iPod/iPad.